# memory utilization very high aspx web page that calls a web service

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf

I have a web page that calls a web service (added web reference) frequently, after hosting site memory utilization is become very high. My code is as follows ..

```
private string callWebService(string Vendor, int ProcessID,
                              string CalledOn, string ReferenceNo,
                              string ReceivedOn, int userId, string password)
{

    string webResponse = "";

    DateTime rcvdOn = Convert.ToDateTime(ReceivedOn);

    string ProxyServer = Convert.ToString(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ProxyServer"]);

    WebReference.MReceived dTW = new WebReference.MReceived();
    WebReference.AHeader authHead = new WebReference.AHeader();

    IWebProxy proxy = new WebProxy(ProxyServer, true);
    try
    {
        dTW.Proxy = proxy;
        authHead.UserID = userId;
        authHead.Password = password;

        dTW.AuthnHeaderValue = authHead;
        webResponse = dTW.RMC_Received(Vendor, ProcessID, CalledOn, ReferenceNo, rcvdOn);

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        webResponse = ex.ToString();
    }

    finally
    {

        dTW.Dispose();
        dTW = null;
        Vendor = null;
        ProcessID = 0;
        CalledOn = null;
        ReferenceNo = null;
        ReceivedOn = null;
        userId = 0;
        password = null;
        authHead = null;
        ProxyServer = null;
        proxy = null;
    }

    return webResponse;
}
```

Comment: Why the `C` tag? Do you mean to use the `c#` tag instead (they are different languages)?

Comment: ys it is c# wrongly mentioed as c